# bootstrap datetimepicker not showing date from database

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="calLeaseStartDate" 
required ng-model="item.StartDate" 
datetimepicker-format="MM/DD/YYYY" options="gridDatePickerOption"
placeholder="Start Date" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

my javascript code while loading from database.

```
angular.forEach($scope.commissionStatement.ComLeaseCalcList, function(item) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(item.StartDate))
    {
        if (item.StartDate !== null) {
            item.StartDate = moment(item.StartDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");                      
        }
     }                     
});
```

It is an angular application. This date is inside a table in html. It is working fine while choosing a date and saving in database. But it is not showing the date from database while loading.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try storing `$scope.item.StartDate= moment(item.StartDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");`

Comment: @Pradeepb.. Wonderful.. that showed the required date, but is showing like 2020-07-01T00:00:00, i have given the format tobe MM/DD/YYYY.. Thank you..

Comment: It should work properly. could you please post what is the value of StartDate you are receiving from db?

Comment: @Pradeepb sorry. It did'nt work..I tested removing "datetimepicker" in html, it did show the date.. but picker will not work.. I tested adding scope at this stage.. Once I added back the "datetimepicker", it did not work.. when I use scope, it is throwing unable to set property StartDate of undefined or null reference. item is the object inside foreach condition

Comment: have a look at this example. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaxJrX?editors=1010

Comment: $scope.gridDatePickerOption = {
        format: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        showClear: true,
        showTodayButton: true
        
    };

Comment: I am using those options to declare. I am not using a directive. All other functionalities are working fine. can you suggest any other way.. Appreciate your efforts in helping me.

Comment: Even if you are not using directive, try to look at how I have set the values to datepicker. I don't see other options than setting the values using jQuery. Sorry. I will be without internet for a day. If it not resolve by then, I will surely look into it more after I return.

Comment: Hi Pradeepb, I am not successful doing that yet.. Do you have any other suggestion.. Thanks

Comment: can you provide the link to which version of datetimepicker you are using and other related libraries?

Comment: I am using bootstrap datetimepicker 4.17.42 version control and moment.js 2.14.3 version.

Comment: Sorry, I tried and was not able to solve. I think only option left is to use directive.